# Writing a jquery plugin in coffeescript - how to get "(function($)" and "(jQuery)"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am writing a jquery plugin in coffeescript but am not sure how to get the function wrapper part right.

My coffeescript starts with this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    myplugin: ->
        @each ->
```

Which creates the javascript with a function wrapper:

```
(function() {
  $.fn.extend({
      myplugin: function() {
          return this.each(function() {
```

but I want a '$' passed in like this:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
```

Similar for the ending I have... nothing in particular in coffeescript.
I get this in javascript:

```
})();
```

But would like this:

```
})(jQuery);
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this with the coffeescript compiler?
Or what is the best way to get this done within coffeescript?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The answer is that you don't need to call it like that in CoffeeScript -- your script is already safely wrapped in a closure, so there's no need for jQuery-passed-in-as-a-parameter-tricks. Just write:

```
$ = jQuery
```

... at the top of your script, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 19):

Unless you're using the `--bare` flag in the compiler, the

```
$ = jQuery
```

solution is best. If you *are*, then with the new `do` keyword, you can write

```
do ($ = jQuery) ->
   # plugin code...
```

thus creating the desired scope while avoiding a mess o' parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE/EDIT:** Yep, as per Jeremy's explanation:

```
$ = jQuery

$.fn.myPlugin = () ->
  console.log('test fired')
```

*compiles to:*

```
(function() {
  var $;
  $ = jQuery;
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    return console.log('test fired');
  };
}).call(this);
```

Which works just fine as a jQuery plugin: `$('body').myPlugin();`

**Original:**

Okay, i think I may getting close on this one, let me know if it helps.

```
(($) ->
  $.fn.extend =
    myplugin: ->
    @each: ->
)(jQuery)
```

renders into:

```
(function() {
  (function($) {
    return $.fn.extend = {
      myplugin: function() {},
      this.each: function() {}
    };
  })(jQuery);
}).call(this);
```

Comment: The second code block you have there is a bit redundant. `jQuery` is being accessed from the global scope anyway, so the inner closure just adds more code (and longer scope chains) for no benefit.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to extend **$.fn** object

Simple jQuery plugin can be written in CoffeeScript as follows:

```
$.extend $.fn,

  disable: ->
    @each ->
      e = $(this)
      e.attr("disabled", "disabled") if e.is("button") or e.is("input")
```

it will compile to

```
(function() {
  $.extend($.fn, {
    disable: function() {
      return this.each(function() {
        var e;
        e = $(this);
        if (e.is("button") || e.is("input")) {
          return e.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
      });
    }
  });
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the CoffeeScript version of jQuery Boilerplate ~ https://github.com/zenorocha/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/jquery.boilerplate.coffee

Comment: https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.coffee

Answer (score 2):

Although this post is old I found it useful. Here is the coffee-script code that works for me.

```
$ -> 
    $('.my-class').hello()

$.fn.hello=-> 
    @each -> 
        $(@).append $ '<div>Hello</div>'
```

**Note**: You don't need to declare the `$` variable, you can just use it right out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add the closure yourself and compile it with the `--bare` flag.

`coffee -w -c --bare jquery.plugin.coffee`

```
(($) ->
  # some code here
)(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simple and Straightforward

This is all I had to do in order to add my own method, `cleanFadeIn`, on jQuery objects. It returns the objects for chaining as well:

```coffee
$.fn.extend
  cleanFadeIn: ->                     # $('.notice').cleanFadeIn
    return $(@).each ->               # returns the objects for easy chaining.
      $(@).slideDown 'slow', ->
        $(@).fadeTo 'slow', 1
```