# CoffeeScript creating a wrapper function with passed arguments

Tags: coffeescript, wrapper

How can I generate this output with CoffeScript?

```
(function(doc) {})(document);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
((doc) ->
)(document)
```

will generate

```
(function(doc) {})(document);
```

If you're asking in the context of wrapping something in a closure - for instance a JQuery plugin - this will not be needed. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533848/writing-a-jquery-plugin-in-coffeescript-how-to-get-function-and-jquery)

Comment: I'm deleting my response since it's the same. We answered at exactly the same time.

Comment: One thing I did add: "You don't generally need to do this since your CoffeeScript is enclosed in a similar anonymous function by default."

Answer (score 10):

Not exactly what you have asked, but the spirit of the code is the same and it is more coffeescriptish :

```
do (document) ->
   # whatever
```

which compiles to

```
(function(document) {})(document);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do (doc=document) ->
```

compiles to

```
(function(doc) {})(document);
```