# Coffeescript "return" and jQuery plugin authoring - with templates

Tags: design-patterns, jquery-plugins, coffeescript

I found this [CoffeeScript boilerplate for jQuery plugins](http://kaibun.net/blog/2013/04/19/a-fully-fledged-coffeescript-boilerplate-for-jquery-plugins/) which I have been studying and *[trying to]* use in a plugin that I'm *[trying to]* write. I have referenced the same boilerplate/template in a few other questions. I am an amateur at JavaScript and a complete new-comer to CoffeeScript. I'm trying to study and learn, but when something bothers me and I can't find a satisfactory answer through Google, I come here... So forgive my lack of knowledge and potential mistakes in any code that I write and present here.

The CoffeeScript code compiles to this:

```
(function() {
    (function($, window, document) {
        var $this, methods, _anotherState, _flag, _internals, _settings;
        $this = void 0;
        _settings = {
            "default": 'cool!'
        };
        _flag = false;
        _anotherState = null;
        methods = {
            init: function(options) {
                $this = $(this);
                $.extend(_settings, options || {});
                return $this;
            },
            doSomething: function(what) {
                return $this;
            },
            destroy: function() {
                return $this;
            }
        };
        _internals = {
            toggleFlag: function() {
                return _flag = !_flag;
            },
            computeSomething: function(state, flag) {
                return flag != null ? flag : {
                    state: "No, that's not right."
                };
            }
        };
        return $.fn.foobar = function(method) {
            if (methods[method]) {
                return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            } else if (typeof method === "object" || !method) {
                return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
            } else {
                return $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist on jquery.foobar");
            }
        };
    })(jQuery, window, document);

}).call(this);
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106686/coffeescript-and-jquery-plugin-authoring) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148261/jquery-plugin-authoring-in-coffeescript-with-conventionally-private-objects-a) I understand that the `(function(){...}).call(this)` wrapper, is a CoffeeScript feature and is meant to localize variables that are not explicitly declared to be global. *I later learnt that it can be suppressed during compilation too*. I also learned that I did not need to include `window` and `document` as arguments to the jQuery closure.

As I studied it more (and tried to edit it), I saw that in the compiled code, the closure (which is a function) returns `$.fn.foobar` right where it defines it. Since that function is anonymous and isn't gonna be called anyway, I suppose the returned value doesn't matter. But still, what if I put a `return` statement in the CoffeeScript code like this:

```
$.fn.foobar = (method) ->
  if methods[method]
    methods[method].apply this, Array::slice.call(arguments, 1)
  else if typeof method is "object" or not method
    methods.init.apply this, arguments
  else
    $.error "Method " + method + " does not exist on jquery.foobar"
# -- This, right here...
return
# --
```

It no longer compiles to `return $.fn.foobar = ...` but instead just `$.fn.foobar = ...`. I think that doesn't make any difference, rather it makes the JS output more... *clean*... if you will. But I need to confirm that. How does that effect the execution of the script?

Moreover, in the CoffeeScript code, the author says that inside `methods.init()` I need to perform all operations on `$this.each` but instead, if I do

```
  init: (options) ->
    $.extend _settings, (options or {})
    return $(@).each () -> # I don't really need return, do I?
      # In here @ is one element (out of the array of elements)
      return # This is to suppress any returns inside .each()
```

So this is it... Here are my **questions**:

1. Is there a reason not to `return` from the anonymous function in the CoffeeScript code? How exactly does that differ from the original CoffeeScript code?
2. What would be a proper way to iterate over all items in the jQuery array on which the plugin is called, while maintaining chainability.

---

**NOTE**: I did not include the CoffeeScript code to avoid the post getting too long. But I have provided a link to the page where the code is listed. However, if it's a trouble, do let me know in comments and I shall edit the post to contain the CoffeeScipt code, too. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What kind of 'chainability' do you have in mind?

Comment: @hpaulj Chainability as in `$('#id.class').plugin(args).someOtherjQueryFunction(args)`. That is only possible if `plugin` returns `$('#id.class')`. And if `$('#id.class')` corresponds to an array of elements instead of just one elements, all of these elements should be returned, not just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the more elaborate boilerplates.  He talks about following the guidelines, but then complicates things by implementing one `foobar` plugin, with delegates things to multiple `methods`.  This obscures what is returned and how chaining is supposed to work.  I don't see this level of complexity in the 'Advanced Plugin' page that he references (http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/)

It might help to compare it with simpler ones

http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/jquery/plugin

https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.coffee

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049128/901925
a coffeescript script that creates 2 plugins, and connects them to a `flot` plot.  It is an adaptation of a `flot` javascript example.  Note the use of `$ ->`, `$.fn.pluginname ->`, and `$('element').plugin()`.  Those are the key jQuery pieces.

A coffeescript function just returns the last item.  The fact that it returns the function is not important if the caller does not use the return value.  What matters when creating a plugin is that $.fn gets a new attribute (some use `extend` to add several attributes).

If the plugin uses `@each`, and is called with something like `$("li").myplugin()` then each element is used

```
$.fn.myplugin = (options) ->
  @each ()->
    console.log 'adding plugin to ',@
```

The boilerplate mentions this in a comment

```
#  $this.each (index, el) ->
#    # do something with el
```

A better way to integrate these ideas might be to go through the learn.jquery pages, and write the scripts in Coffeescript.  They are short enough that you can use the browser based interpreter that shows coffeescript and javascript side by side.

Comment: What do you think about this one: the [Lightweight jQuery Plugin Boilerplate](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/). If I convert it to CoffeeScript, that is...

Comment: I see that the second link you provided ([this](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.coffee) one) actually implements the one I mentioned in the comment above. While I hadn't yet come across CoffeeScript I used this one in JavaScript as my default plugin template. It's nice and solid. But it doesn't provide the `$(element).plugin('method', methodOpts)` functionality. Because once the plugin has been called on an element, it cannot be called again. Can you suggest a way to implement dynamic update-ability with this template?

Comment: The `if !$.data(@, "plugin_#{pluginName}")` line prevents plugin from being installed a 2nd time.  I'd try changing it to `if true` or omitting it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it ([see the whole source in GitHub](https://github.com/davesag/coffeescript-jquery-plugin-template) including examples of how to unit test a Coffeescript jQuery plugin using QUnit, and how to build it to minified version with sourceMap.)

```
throw "Expected jQuery to have been loaded before this script."  if typeof jQuery isnt "function"
(($) ->

  # Main jQuery Collection method.
  $.fn.myPlugin = (options) ->
    self = this
    opts = $.extend true, {}, $.fn.myPlugin.options
    @options = if typeof options is "object"
      $.extend(true, opts, options)
    else
      opts
    @each ->
      $this = $(this)

      # TODO: do pluginy stuff with $this

      return $this # because it's chainable.

  # defaults
  $.fn.myPlugin.options =
    whatever: true
) jQuery
```

The corresponding `QUnit` test looks like

```
(($) ->

  module "basic tests",

    setup: ->
      this.elems = $("#qunit-fixture").children(".qunit-container")

  # all jQuery plugins must be chainable.
  test "is chainable", ->
    expect(1)
    strictEqual(this.elems.myPlugin(), this.elems, "should be chainable")

) jQuery
```

I hope that helps.