# How do I create a jQuery plugin in CoffeeScript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, coffeescript, scope

On [How to Create a Basic Plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) there is a section titled **Protecting the $ Alias and Adding Scope**.

> The $ variable is very popular among JavaScript libraries, and if
>   you're using another library with jQuery, you will have to make jQuery
>   not use the $ with jQuery.noConflict(). However, this will break our
>   plugin since it is written with the assumption that $ is an alias to
>   the jQuery function. To work well with other plugins, and still use
>   the jQuery $ alias, we need to put all of our code inside of an
>   Immediately Invoked Function Expression, and then pass the function
>   jQuery, and name the parameter $:

In JavaScript, this wrapper looks like this:

```
(function ( $ ) {
  // do stuff
  return this;
})(jQuery)
```

How can this be translated into CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This coffeescript:

```
$ = jQuery
### do stuff ###
```

compiles to:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
  var $;
  $ = jQuery;
  /* do stuff*/
}).call(this);
```

I think the effect is the same, ensuring that `$` points to `jQuery` regardless of what `$` is in the calling environment.

This is what the author of Coffeescript recommends in [Writing a jquery plugin in coffeescript - how to get "(function($)" and "(jQuery)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533848/writing-a-jquery-plugin-in-coffeescript-how-to-get-function-and-jquery?rq=1)

To get closer to the original pattern (`do` is still something of a blackbox to me)

```
do ($=jQuery) ->
  ### do stuff  ###
  @
```

'bare' compiles to:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function($) {
  /* do stuff*/

  return this;
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

At first it's non-obvious.  Here's the skeleton.

```
$.fn.ourFunction = do ($=jQuery) -> (opts) ->
  # do stuff
  @
```

It compiles to this:

```
$.fn.ourFunction = (function($) {
  return function(opts) {
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

---

We could also split this into several lines for clarity.

```
$.fn.ourFunction = do ($=jQuery) ->
  (opts) ->
    # do stuff
    @
```

Our first line uses the `do` syntax, which runs a function initially.  We can also specify parameters (e.g. `$`), and their values (e.g. `jQuery`).

```
$.fn.ourFunction = do ($=jQuery) ->
```

Our second line creates a function, which is returned.  Remember, everything in CoffeeScript is an expression, so we don't need to say `return (opts) ->` (but you can).

```
(opts) ->
```

Then, there's of course the body of our code, where the actual work happens.  One trick that I left out of the initial code is to use the `=>` operator to maintain scope.  Inside our scroll handler, we can force `this` to remain our targeted object.  We could call `$('#something').ourFunction()` and we effectively call `$('#something').something()` in our scroll handler.

```
$.fn.ourFunction = do ($=jQuery) ->
  (opts) ->
    $(window).scroll =>
      this.something()
      @something()
    @
```

Our last line is simply the `@` character.  This allows chaining, because we're returning `this`.  Alternatively, if our last line calls another chainable method on `this`, we don't need to make it explicit.

```
$.fn.flash = do ($=jQuery) -> (opts) ->
  @animate(opacity: 0).delay()
   .animate({opacity: 1})
```